# How to save serial data in .txt format using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am real-time plotting the serial data in MATLAB using EMG sensor but I could not find a way to store that data in a .txt file, so that later I can load this file using load command e.g: `load('emg.txt')`.

Which command would help me to save this file?

I have tried few commands like `save` but not of any help.

```
s = serial('COM5','baudrate',9600);   %(I want to save this in .txt format)
fopen(s)
tic
for serialcounter = 1: 2000
    sig = [sig str2num(fscanf(s))];
end
time = toc
fclose(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

**For .bin files:**

fwrite: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html

Something like this:

```
s = serial('COM5','baudrate',9600);   %(I want to save this in .txt format)
fopen(s)
newFileID = fopen('new_file.bin','w');
tic
for serialcounter = 1: 2000
    sig = [sig str2num(fscanf(s))];
    fwrite(newFileID, sig);
end
time = toc
fclose(s)
fclose(newFileID);
```

**For .txt files:**

fprintf: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

```
s = serial('COM5','baudrate',9600);   %(I want to save this in .txt format)
fopen(s)
newFileID = fopen('new_file.txt','w');
tic
for serialcounter = 1: 2000
    sig = [sig str2num(fscanf(s))];
    fprintf(newFileID, '%... %...\n', sig);
end
time = toc
fclose(s)
fclose(newFileID);
```